# Collect paths from a Node

Tags: xml, scala

I want to collect a Set of paths from an `xml.Node`. I have working code, but it is ugly. I'd like some help to clean it up (or perhaps a better solution?)

```
import xml._

def paths(node: Node): Set[String] = {
  def inner(base: String, node: Node): Set[String] = {
    if (node.isInstanceOf[Elem]) {
      val newBase = "%s/%s".format(base, node.label)
      val selfAndChildren = node.child.flatMap(
        inner(newBase, _)).toSet.asInstanceOf[Set[String]] + newBase
      val attributes = node.attributes.map(a => 
        "%s/@%s".format(newBase, a.key)).toSet.asInstanceOf[Set[String]]
      selfAndChildren ++ attributes
    } else Set.empty[String]
  }
  inner("", node)
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> val x = <a><b z="true"><c>3</c></b></a>
x: scala.xml.Elem = <a><b z="true"><c>3</c></b></a>

scala> paths(x)                               
res1: Set[String] = Set(/a/b/c, /a/b, /a/b/@z, /a)
```

What I don't like:

- The type system forced me to cast the results of `toSet`
- I expected something in the XML API to get the fully qualified path of any `Element`
- I don't like to use the `isInstanceOf[T]` check, but could not get pattern matching to work.
- It's way too verbose.

Comment: Why are attributes in the path? I was thinking the paths in your example are /a/b/c, /a/b, /a. Confused about /a/b/@z.

Comment: My particular kooky needs dictate that I need this in the output. The detail is that I'm making a builder that is configured to clone nodes and attributes to a nasty vendor framework's API. I plug in all the paths I am interested in and then walk the XML. Any paths that match are created in the vendor's API and the values copied. I need to copy attributes, so they are present here. It probably should be /a/b@z instead (to be xpath like) but the exact notation is not important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Purely looking at the style rather than the algorithm:

```
def paths(node: Node): Set[String] = {
  def inner(base: String, node: Node): Set[String] = node match {
    case n:Elem =>
      val newBase = base + "/" + n.label
      (Set(newBase) 
        ++ n.child.flatMap(inner(newBase, _))
        ++ n.attributes.map(base + "/@" + _.key))
    case _ => Set.empty
  }
  inner("", node)
}
```

I think that helps with the verbosity, the instance check and class casts.